# URI Malformed Error Javascript Google Has That Problem Too?

Tags: javascript, uri, decode, encode, malformed

İ make a search engine for my blog with javascript and i use just hashes for url.
When i insert adress "https://test.com/#s=%90" i have error at my browser console "URI malformed" because of decodeURIComponent then i try that solution:

```js
window.location.hash = "%90çö%25";
try{
  var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash);
}
 catch(e){
   var url = decodeURIComponent(window.location.hash.replace(/\%/g, "%25"));
}
 console.log(url);
```

but in firefox and chrome result is: "#%90%C3%A7%C3%B6%25" i want result: "#%90çö%25"

After that i think that solution:

```
1-)Get "window.location.hash"
2-)Try decodeURIComponent
3-)İf it has "URI malformed" error find which percent character make that error
4-)Replace %90 to %2590(which percent characters make error replace all % to %25) then try decodeURIComponent
5-)Expected result: "#%90çö%25"
```

But i can't write that plan to code… İ tryed from yesterday but i can't solve that problem yet.

And Google has that error too: https://www.google.com/search?q=%90&oq=%90 look at console.

İs it possible to solve that "URİ malformed" problem like that ?

Comment: what character do you expect `%90` to be? There has to be something > `%C0` right before that `%90`

Comment: %90 is just a example. İf any like %90 character make URI malformed error then just replace it to %2590 that is what i wanted...

Comment: `%90 is just a example` but that `%90` is exactly what makes this URL malformed. So what's the point of having `%90` there? Where does this string/character come from? Why `%90` and not something valid? This is invalid UTF-8 encoding

Comment: İf user enter %90 in search engine or directly enter url that character then that error occur. İ know we can do all % characters to %25 at input but i want to solve when directly url entered %90

Comment: if you want to fix the user input, then `window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent(userInput);` and you have no problems with invalid encodeing or malformed URLs

Comment: But i must use decodeURIComponent because i write page what user has url characters. For example: "nasılsın" i must use decodeURIComponent to show page content: "nasılsın" too

Comment: Correct! So what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is when user enter %90 directly at url javascript can't decode it then uri malformed error occur. İ want %90(which characters can not decode) to %2590 replace with javascript…

Comment: @Thomas is javascript can select only which characters can not decode with decodeURİComponent?